# Is there a way to run a node task in a child process?

Tags: node.js

I have a node server, which needs to:

1. Serve the web pages
2. Keep querying an external REST API and save data to database and send data to clients for certain updates from REST API.

Task 1 is just a normal node tasks. But I don't know how to implement the task 2. This task won't expose any interface to outside. It's more like a background task.

Can anybody suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a second node.js app that runs at the same time as your first one, you can just create another node.js app and then run it from your first one using `child_process.spawn()`.  It can regularly query the external REST API and update the database as needed.

The part about ***"Send data to clients for certain updates from REST API"*** is not so clear what you're trying to do.

If you're using socket.io to send data to connected browsers, then the browsers have to be connected to your web server which I presume is your first node.js process.  To have the second node.js process cause data to be sent through the socket.io connections in the first node.js process, you need some interprocess way to communicate.  You can use stdout and stdin via `child_process.spawn()`, you can use some feature in your database or any of several other IPC methods.

Because querying a REST API and updating a database are both asynchronous operations, they don't take much of the CPU of a node.js process.  As such, you don't really have to do these in another node.js process.  You could just have a `setInterval()` in your main node.js process, query the API every once in a while, update the database when results are received and then you can directly access the socket.io connections to send data to clients without having to use a separate process and some sort of IPC mechanism.

Comment: I'm going to use socket.io to send data to client (a web page).

Comment: @bagusflyer - I added some info to my answer if you're using socket.io to send data to connected browsers.

Comment: I tried setInterval(), it also works. But I'm wondering which is better. Is child process running in anther thread? Will it save CPU time?

Comment: @bagusflyer- A child process is running in another process (which is a separate thread).  The last paragraph of my answer contains comments about the CPU time.  I would say "don't make it any more complicated than necessary".  If you're getting perfectly acceptable performance using `setInterval()` and have no problem with that design, then stick with that as it is much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**Task 1:** 
Express is good way to accomplish this task.
You can explore:
http://expressjs.com/

**Task 2:**

If you are done with Expressjs. Then you can write your logic with in Express Framework. 
This task then can be done with node module **[forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)**. Its a simple tool that runs your background scripts forever. You can use forever to run scripts continuously (whether it is written in node.js or not)

Have a look:
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: Is it possible to run this task inside the same node app?

Comment: I don't understand how forever is an answer to this question.  forever is a tool that keeps a process running and auto-restarts it if it crashes.  It isn't a tool for doing what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @bagusflyer if you are doing it in the same node app. You will need to have a **cron job** setup for that on your server as per your requirement.

Comment: @jfriend00 forever is used to isolate the background tasks from other normal activities.

Comment: I think you are confused here.  That's not what forever does.  If the second node.js app is just run as it's own app, it is already isolated from other activities.  forever doesn't provide any extra isolation.  Pretty much ALL forever does is restart the app when it stops functioning.

Comment: Thanks, understand. I need to run the process in the same app.